# Replacing text with RegEx and C# isn't working the way I need it to

Tags: c#, regex, string

I’m looking for a way to go through a string and replace all instances where the second and third characters will always be different but the rest will be the same. For example, if I had:

```
"ú07ú" to be replaced with "ú07 ú" 
"ú1Eú" to be replaced with "ú1E ú"
"ú12ú" to be replaced with "ú12 ú"
```

I know I should use Regular Expressions, but they baffle me. I’m pretty sure the syntax will be something like:

```
Content = Regex.Replace(Content, @"ú...", “ú.. ú");
```

But obviously this isn’t working. Can any RegEx gurus lend a hand please?

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking at strings that have that format you can just do string manipulation instead of a Regex. `Content = Content.Insert( ... )`. Just another way to look at it if your problem is this simple.

Comment: I would have but Regex provides me the ability to use wildcards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
Content = Regex.Replace(Content, @"ú([^ú]+)ú", @"ú$1 ú");
```

This regex:

```
ú([^ú]+)ú
```

Means: match ú, then at least one character that isn't ú (and capture this part), then another ú. If you want it to only match *exactly* two characters in the middle, then change `[^ú]+` to `[^ú]{2}`

Then we replace the whole thing by:

```
ú$1 ú
```

Which is: ú, then the captured part of the string, then a space and ú again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally unfamiliar with C#, but from a regex perspective you need capturing groups.

"ú..." needs to be "(ú...)(.)" and “ú.. ú" needs to be "$1 $2" assuming C# uses the standard regex notation for capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestMethod]
public void regex_test()
{
  string expr = @"(?<firstThree>.{3})(?<lastOne>.{1})";
  string replace = "${firstThree} ${lastOne}";

  string first = "u84u";
  string firstResult = "u84 u";

  Assert.AreEqual<string>(firstResult, Regex.Replace(first, expr, replace));
}
```